# Trying to identify a Sci-fi short, in which aliens monitor and rank other races, and are shocked humans used fission devices in the atmosphere

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

Does anyone recognise this, please?

(I know I found this story again a few years ago, and read it using the Kindle app, but it doesn't show in the app or my account)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, are you able to provide any more details about where and when you might have first read the story? What year? Was it in an anthology? That sort of thing. When you are able please [edit] in that information, and then please do take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like Isaac Asimov's (very) short story *Silly Asses*.

[Read it here.](https://supernovacondensate.net/2012/06/23/isaac-asimov-silly-asses/)

[Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silly_Asses).

> The people of Earth have developed atomic power. As such, they are recorded by Naron the Rigellian, the long-lived Keeper of the galactic records, as having achieved maturity. But when the keeper learns that they have not yet penetrated space and that they test their atomic weapons on their own planetary surface, he strikes them from the record, commenting that Earth people are 'Silly Asses'.

Comment: Yes, Silly Asses was the one! Many thinks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

David Weber's *Out of the Dark*, initially published as part of *[Warriors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AEBUPSM)*, seems to match at least partially.

Civilizations are ranked:

> The problem was that the Hegemony Council's authorization for this
> operation was based on the survey team's report that the objective's
> intelligent species had achieved only a Level Six civilization.  The
> other two systems on Thikair's list were both classified as Level Five
> civilizations, although one had crept close to the the boundary
> between Level Five and Level Four.

But the aliens were shocked not by fission devices, but by the continued use of hydrocarbons despite having fission:

> "In fact, preliminary analysis suggests they've already developed
> fission power - possibly even fusion.  But while there are at least
> *some* fission power sources on the planet, there seem to be very few of them.  In fact, most of their power generation seems to come from
> burning *hydrocarbons*!  Why would any civilization that was really
> Level Two do anything that stupid?"

The story was later extended and published as a standalone novel IIRC.

Comment: Thanks. Not the one, but I'll have to read that :-)